# Turning of captcha on Google Apps

Tags: google-apps-script, admin, google-drive-api, captcha, google-apps-for-education

I am generating Drive-folders on a Google Apps For Education domain.
Im running a Google Apps Script-program as an admin that uses the DriveApp. Every folder is shared to a group or user.
After about 100 folders i got an error and on the rerun I got in on the first folder. 
When doing the equivalent task manually, I get a captcha-popup.

Conclusion: The captcha-requests renders my program useless. I most turn of captcha or make my program to handle them.
What can I do?

Comment: After about 10 captcha-checks, it was back to normal.

Comment: Turns out you can't turn of captcha. It's a build-in feature.

Comment: You may try one of the following workarounds:
- Include exponential backoff into the script so that it automatically retries once it gets an error. Please refer to this article for more details on this https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/ExponentialBackoff
- You may share the folder publicly or "Anyone with the link can access" and then provide the link to the users via email
- You may also share the folder publicly, and embed it into a shared access point for these users (for example a website or an intranet).